# What is the shortcut called for inverting the sculpt brush

Tags: sculpting, shortcut

The default way to invert a sculpt brush is through ctrl left click. I already have ctrl left click set to something else, so I'd like to change the shortcut. I looked through the keymap but nothing seems to be for inverting the brush.
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's under *3D View > Sculpt > Sculpt (Global) > Sculpt (Ctrl Left Mouse)*:

[image]

Comment: For the second part of your answer: can you find it by typing "Ctrl Left Mouse" when this shortcut is already assigned to something else though?

Comment: @Gordon Brinkmann I'm not sure what you mean, you can find it under Sculpt as shown in my screenshot

Comment: I know and I never doubted that. I said, the second part where you alternatively search for the key binding - will that work when the shortcut is already assigned to a different option as stated in the question? Otherwise this alternative  will not give the desired result.

Comment: Oh yes of course you're right